# for loop makes pause every 8 million iterations - why?

Tags: java

When I run the following code on Intellij with input 1000000000000 the process holds a moment every 8 million loops.

Why is it like this? Why doesn't run in one smoothly flow until the end?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please type a number");
        long n = in.nextLong();
        System.out.println("Thanks.");

        long count = 0;
        for (long i=0; i<=n; i++) {
            if ((n+i) == (n^i)) {
                count++;
                if (count % 1000000 == 0)
                System.out.println(count);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you determine the "pause"?

Comment: Just looking at the stdout. It stops every 8 million iterations.

Comment: @RichArt it doesn't "stop" every 8 million iterations. It's still running. It's just that you only print something every million times that `(n+i) == (n^i)`.

Comment: Yes, but the thing ist that it prints until 8 million and then it stops, then it prints again until 16 million and it stops again, and so on.

Comment: @AndyTurner I believe he understands that. My impression is that he is saying every eighth print statement seems to take longer than the 7 before.

Comment: is the bitwise xor correct in your code (n^i)? (It is not the mathematical power, maybe that is your error? )

Comment: It doesn't even pause after 8 million iterations. The first `System.out.println(count);` occurs when `i = 22,577,727`.

Comment: yes, xor is correct. After the eighth statements it makes a small pause until printing the ninth statement.

Comment: Somebody tried it out and got the same symptom?

Comment: I just tried and suspect the pauses occur since the condition `(n+1) != (n^i)` occurs more frequently as `i` gets larger.

Comment: @PEF: But I have the problem with `(n+1) == (n^i)`

Comment: yes, and I was saying that `(n+1) == (n^i)` is true less and less often as `i` grows larger and larger.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The condition

```
(n + i) == (n ^ i)
```

will occur mostly when there are no overlapping bits in `n` and `i`, since in that case addition and XOR are basically the same thing.

For example, if `n == 4` and `i == 3`, then in binary `n == 100` and `i == 011`, so

```
 n + i == 100 + 011 == 111 == 7
 n ^ i == 100 ^ 011 == 111 == 7
```

I'm not convinced that there are no numbers with bits in common for which the condition also holds; but these are the "obvious" cases for which it is true.

The binary form of 1000000000000 is

```
1110100011010100101001010001000000000000
```

The least significant set bit here is the 12th bit (starting from zero-th at the right).

The 12th power of 2 is 4096. So, all of the numbers less than 4096 have no bits in common with `n`, so you'll count all the numbers 0-4095. From that point on, you'll only count the numbers which don't have the 12th bit set. So, the rate of counting numbers will slow down.

Then, you'll hit the 16th LSB. Now, you'll only count numbers without the 12th and 16th bits set. So, the rate of counting numbers will slow down some more.

etc etc.

The only reason for these "pauses" is the outer for loop naively iterates over all numbers up to `n`: it doesn't simply skip to the next number for which the condition holds.

Comment: And you can see that this is indeed the case by running the program with an input of, say, 1048576, which is 1 << 20 and therefore has all lower bits zero.

Comment: @Andy: you wrote "I'm not convinced that there are no numbers with bits in common for which the condition also holds". Can you make an example? I cannot understand what you mean.

Comment: @RichArt if I could give an example, I'd be convinced that such an example existed! There may not be; I just don't want to claim that because I'm not inclined to prove it.

Comment: I don't understand why the counting rate is slowing down. Because the 12th bit is not set to `1`? So, the evaluation of `(1000000000000 + 4095) == (1000000000000 ^ 4095)` is faster than `(1000000000000 + 4096) == (1000000000000 ^ 4096)`? But why?

Comment: @RichArt No, the evaluation time of the expression has no significant impact here. It's just that there are longer and longer "gaps" where nothing gets printed because the expression evaluates to `false`.

Comment: @Hulk @Andy, but then I do not agree with the explanation because it counts fast until 8 million, then it pauses and then it counts again until 16 million and then it pauses and then it counts again until... etc. If it were as you say, then it should have a steady slow down as the variable `i` gets bigger, right? But it isn't the case.

Comment: @RichArt the "pause" gets longer each time. Just add an `else`-block where you print the other, non-matching values too in a way that makes it easy to distinguish them from the original ones.

Comment: The reason you're not seeing the pause increasing in length is that the frequency with which you are printing the message (every 1e6 matching elements) is too coarse. Plus, I have found that the pause becomes longer than I'm inclined to wait after 134 million. If you actually look for the runs of matching/non-matching numbers, you find that the maximum run length of non-matching numbers increases with `i` - not smoothly, but in steps corresponding to the set bits in `n`. It is iterating over these non-matching runs that causes what you call a "pause".

Comment: @Hulk: ok, I agree with you, that the pause you mean gets longer with a bigger `i`. But it doesn't explain why it pauses at 8 million and then it flows again until 16 million. Did you try it out on your PC?

Comment: @AndyTurner, yes I just ran a test with printing `i` and `count` together (`System.out.println(i+ ", "+count);`). And now I think got the point: I guess `i` is the whole time counting normally but `count` is counting much, much less between 8 and 9 million and between 16 and 17 million, and so on. Or is there something else that I didn't get?

Comment: @RichArt yes, it's that straightforward.